# VBA(?) How to extract filename of images linked and inserted - Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2013

We insert and link pictures (insert picture from file .emf) in our Word documents (.docx). Our documents and the graphic files are stored on our network drives. We then provide our documents to the authors to be worked on. The pictures in the documents are useful for the authors.

How do I programmatically and globally (document wise, not batch processing documents): Extract the filename (without the file extension) of the pictures linked and inserted?

We have a tool that exports the Word document .docx to .XML.

Ps: I googled for possible/potential VBA solutions. So far, I gather:

1. there’s no way one can be sure / check that the pictures have been linked and inserted properly / correctly in a .docx
2. there’s no way to view the source code (? at least I tried Alt+ F9 / Shift+F9)

Or is macro/ vba not the way to go?

**Specs:**
Word 2013.
64 bit
Graphic format. Emf
Graphic and word documents store on a network drive
Graphics not inserted and linked via the INCLUDEPICTURE field.

Comment: Are these pictures inserted in-line with the text or with text wrap formatting? That affects how they can be addressed via the object model (VBA), or via WordOpenXML. FWIW the default with the graphics engine introduced in Word 2013 tries to avoid using IncludePicture - a mistake, in my opinion, but apparently some people find field codes... intimidating.

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for the tip and helping out with my first post here. The pictures are with text wrapping around it.

Answer (score 2):

To get a listing of floating and inline linked pictures alike, you might use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Shp As Shape, iShp As InlineShape, StrOut As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  StrOut = "Linked Shapes:"
  For Each Shp In .ShapeRange
    With Shp
      If .Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
        StrOut = StrOut & Chr(11) & Split(.LinkFormat.SourceName, ".")(0)
      End If
    End With
  Next
  If InStr(StrOut, Chr(11)) = 0 Then StrOut = StrOut & " None."
  .InsertAfter vbCr & StrOut
  StrOut = "Linked InlineShapes:"
  For Each iShp In .InlineShapes
    With iShp
      If .Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture Then
        StrOut = StrOut & Chr(11) & Split(.LinkFormat.SourceName, ".")(0)
      End If
    End With
  Next
  If InStr(StrOut, Chr(11)) = 0 Then StrOut = StrOut & " None."
  .InsertAfter vbCr & StrOut
End With
End Sub
```

Do note that the above code only searches the document body; not headers, footers, etc. The listings are output at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics formatted with text wrappping fall into the `Shapes` collection. These *cannot* use `IncludePicture` to manage the link - they "live" in a different layer of the document than text and field codes. So the only way to access or manage this information is through the object model (VBA, for example), or through the Word Open XML.

The object model provides the `LinkFormat` property for the `Shape` object to query and manage link information. Among other things, there are properties and methods for breaking the link, getting the file name, the file path and the complete file information.

The following loops all `Shape` objects in the main body of the document and tests whether the type is a linked picture. If it is, the full file information is assigned to `sSource`.

```
Sub GetSourceFromLinkedShape()
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim sSource As String

    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.shapes
      If shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
        sSource = shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```