# Update multiple source links for pictures in WORD 2016 via VBA

Tags: ms-word

I worked on some VBA code to change all the sourcelocation of all the images. However it is detecting only 3 InlineShapes. There are many more. I inserted all images as Insert and LInk

```
Sub ChangesSource()
Dim i As Long
Documents("Document.docx").Activate
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name

With ActiveDocument

For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
With .InlineShapes(i)
'.shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName =


.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, "C:\oldLink", "C:\newLink")

Debug.Print .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
'Debug.Print InlineShapes(i).SourceFullName
End With
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: According to the site guidelines, this is "too broad". It's also not clear if you're looking for a programming solution... Unless you can show some research effort the chances are, this is going to be closed. However, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/50129110/3077495 to see if that doesn't give you a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub ChangeSource()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .InlineShapes(i)
      If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
        With .LinkFormat
          .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, .SourcePath, "C:\NewPath\")
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you save the document in the older .doc format, pressing Alt-F9 will expose the INCLUDEPICTURE fields containing the links. You can then use Find/Replace to update the paths (note the use of \\ for the path separators). Pressing Alt-F9, then Ctrl-Shift-F9 will refresh the linked images. You can then re-save the document in the docx format, if you wish. The other option is to use a macro.

Comment: Thank you, I read in one website that it may be a bit risky to do this way so I decided to write a vba piece of code, however still some issues.

Comment: The only risks concern the use of any features not supported in the older doc format (e.g. content controls, bibliographies).